# Увертюра к опере Кармен

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: Увертюра к опере "Кармен"
Или
Увертюра из оперы "Кармен"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Увертюра ***к опере*** "Кармен".

Увертю́ра (фр. ouverture, от лат. apertura — открытие, начало) — ***инструментальное вступление к*** театральному спектаклю, чаще музыкальному (опере, балету, оперетте).

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B0)